# pgfkeys with length and .is choice

Tags: pgfkeys

I want to define a key to handle a length, but also have custom settings.

The usage I intend:

- `my length = auto` will set a boolean to false and ignore the length
- `my length = half` will set a boolean to true and set the length to `0.5\linewidth`
- `my length = 20pt` will set a boolean to true and set the length to `20pt`

So far, so good, but I'd like to use `my length = \linewidth` or `my length = \myotherlength`, for example, but using a macro* as a key breaks the `.is choice` processing.

- yes, a length in this case :)

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newif\ifisauto
\isautofalse

\newlength{\mylength}

\pgfkeys{
    /my test/.cd,
    my length/.is choice,
    my length/auto/.code = {\isautotrue},
    my length/half/.code = {\isautofalse\setlength{\mylength}{0.5\linewidth}},
    my length/.unknown/.code = {\isautofalse\setlength{\mylength}{\pgfkeyscurrentname}}%  won't work with macros
}

\newcommand{\printinfo}{%
    \ifisauto
        Choice is auto, ignoring \textbackslash mylength%
    \else
        Choice is not auto and \textbackslash mylength is \the\mylength%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

Tests:

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = auto}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = half}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = 20pt}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = \linewidth}%  this fails!
\printinfo

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working without having separate keys for the boolean and the length?

Comment: If I take the opposite way... Is there a way to check if `\pgfkeyscurrentname` is a length or simple text? Just thinking about other possibilities...

Comment: Yes. I think I'll just write my own code... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create this with an altered `.is choice` handler (I'll call it `.is robust choice`). The changes compared to current `pgfkeys`' `.is choice` are:

- The `.unknown` handler can access the unknown value directly via `#1`.
- The choice is matched as a string, so macros don't hurt there.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newif\ifisauto
\isautofalse

\newlength{\mylength}


\makeatletter
% this is based on the definition of the .is choice handler
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.is robust choice/.code=%
  \pgfkeys{%
    \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.cd,%
    .code=%
      \edef\pgfkeys@was@choice{\unexpanded{##1}}%
      \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/\detokenize{##1}/.@cmd}%
        {\expandafter\pgfkeysalso\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/\detokenize{##1}}}%
        {\expandafter\pgfkeysalso\expandafter{\pgfkeyscurrentkey/.unknown={##1}}},
    .unknown/.code={% default .unknown handler of an .is choice
      \def\pgf@marshal{\pgfkeysvalueof{/errors/unknown choice value/.@cmd}}%
      {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgf@marshal\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the\expandafter\pgfkeys@pathtoks\expandafter}\expandafter{\pgfkeys@was@choice}\pgfeov}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{
    /my test/.cd,
    my length/.is robust choice,
    my length/auto/.code = {\isautotrue},
    my length/half/.code = {\isautofalse\setlength{\mylength}{0.5\linewidth}},
    my length/.unknown/.code = {\isautofalse\setlength{\mylength}{#1}}%  won't work with macros
}

\newcommand{\printinfo}{%
    \ifisauto
        Choice is auto, ignoring \textbackslash mylength%
    \else
        Choice is not auto and \textbackslash mylength is \the\mylength%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

Tests:

\typeout{\string\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = auto}}%  OK
\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = auto}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = half}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = 20pt}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = \linewidth}%  this fails!
\printinfo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was working on my own solution, but I'll take a look at this!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use `pgfkeys` you could as well use a key=value implementation that comes with the required behaviour built in, like `expkv-def`. In it you can use a `choice` and set the unknown handler with `unknown-choice`. The `protected` is just there to make the underlying key-code `\protected` (else you'd get problems with your definitions in `\edef` or `\expanded` contexts).

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of `expkv-def`.</sup>

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\newif\ifisauto
\isautofalse

\newlength{\mylength}

\ekvdefinekeys{my test}
  {
    protected choice my length = {
      auto = \isautotrue,
      half = \isautofalse\setlength\mylength{.5\linewidth}
    },
    protected unknown-choice my length = \isautofalse\setlength\mylength{#1}
  }

\newcommand{\printinfo}{%
    \ifisauto
        Choice is auto, ignoring \textbackslash mylength%
    \else
        Choice is not auto and \textbackslash mylength is \the\mylength%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

Tests:

\ekvset{my test}{my length = auto}%  OK
\printinfo

\ekvset{my test}{my length = half}%  OK
\printinfo

\ekvset{my test}{my length = 20pt}%  OK
\printinfo

\ekvset{my test}{my length = \linewidth}%  this fails!
\printinfo

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All the rest of my code uses pgfkeys, but interesting alternatives are good to know

Answer (score 0):

Since using `.is choice` seems unfeasible without changing some interal code, the solution ended up being to do the comparisons manually.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newif\ifisauto
\isautofalse

\newlength{\mylength}

\pgfkeys{
    /my test/.cd,
    my length/.code = {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{auto}{#1}}{%
            \isautotrue%
        }{%
            \isautofalse%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{half}{#1}}{%
                \setlength{\mylength}{0.5\linewidth}%
            }{%
                \setlength{\mylength}{#1}%
            }%
        }%
    },
}

\newcommand{\printinfo}{%
    \ifisauto
        Choice is auto, ignoring \textbackslash mylength%
    \else
        Choice is not auto and \textbackslash mylength is \the\mylength%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

Tests:

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = auto}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = half}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = 20pt}%  OK
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = \linewidth}%  OK now
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = 0.1\linewidth}%  OK now
\printinfo

\pgfkeys{/my test/my length = \dimexpr \linewidth/3 - 2pt}%  OK now
\printinfo

\end{document}
```